# Does memcpy really a copy of the memory?

Tags: c, gcc, memcpy

I'm experimenting with memory handling in C.

Giving the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct Data {
    int valid;
    double value;
} Data;

typedef struct Message {
    int id;
    int size;
    int nr;
    Data *data;
} Message;

int main() {
    int sz = 5;
    int id = 1;
    int i;

    Message msg;
    msg.id = id;
    msg.size = 0;
    msg.nr = sz;
    msg.data = malloc(sizeof(Data) * msg.nr);
    for (i = 0; i < msg.nr; i++) {
        msg.data[i].valid = 1;
        msg.data[i].value = (double)i;
    }

    printf("Input data\nid: %d\nsize: %d\nnr: %d\n",
           msg.id, msg.size, msg.nr);
    
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf("msg.data[%d].valid: %d\nmsg.data[%d].value: %lf\n",
               i, msg.data[i].valid, i, msg.data[i].value);

    int bufferSize = sizeof(msg) + (sizeof(Data) * msg.nr);
    msg.size = bufferSize;
    printf("bufferSize: %d\n", bufferSize);

    BYTE *buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * bufferSize);
    memcpy(buffer, &msg, bufferSize);

    if (msg.data != NULL)
        free(msg.data);
     
    // test
    Message *p = (Message *)buffer;
    Message rcv;
    rcv.id = 0;
    rcv.size = 0;
    rcv.nr = 0;
    rcv.data = malloc(sizeof(Data) * p->nr);

    memcpy(&rcv, buffer, p->size);
    
    printf("Output data\nid: %d\nsize: %d\nnr: %d\n",
           rcv.id, rcv.size, rcv.nr);
    
    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        printf("rcv.data[%d].valid: %d\nrcv.data[%d].value: %lf\n",
               i, rcv.data[i].valid, i, rcv.data[i].value);

    if (rcv.data != NULL)
        free(rcv.data);

    if (buffer != NULL)
        free(buffer);
}
```

I'm obtaining the following error at the end of the execution of the code
`*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated`

Going deeper what I found is that `msg.data` and `rcv.data` point to the same memory address

[memory location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th2Ag.png)

and when I free the `rcv.data` basically I'm releasing a memory location that as been released before.

I read that `memcpy` should create a copy, but I had a different experience.
I don't understand why it's happening.

I use gcc as compiler, and I tried to run the code in different machines, but I obtain the same result always.
Why this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why the code contains undefined behaviors**

The first call to `memcpy` reads starting from the address of `msg` for `bufferSize` bytes, where `bufferSize` is *larger* than the size of `msg` itself. Reading beyond the size of the object causes undefined behaviors.

```c
int bufferSize = sizeof(msg) + (sizeof(Data) * msg.nr);
// This reads beyond the size of `msg`
memcpy(buffer, &msg, bufferSize);
```

The `memcpy` function copies the data byte-by-byte, including the `Data* data` field of `Message`, which is why you're getting the same address for both `msg.data` and `rcv.data`.
`memcpy` does not attempt to create a copy of the array pointed to by the `data` pointer. Copying bytes beyond the end of `msg` also doesn't help, because `msg` (which is on the stack) is not going to be adjacent with the array pointed to by `msg.data` (which is on the heap).

[`memcpy` entry on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy)

**Solution for arbitrary length array**

To fix this, call `memcpy` two times separately to serialize the `Message` and the array of `Data`.

```c
int bufferSize = sizeof(Message) + sizeof(Data) * msg.nr;
BYTE* buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE) * bufferSize);
memcpy(buffer, &msg, sizeof(Message));
memcpy(buffer + sizeof(Message), msg.data, sizeof(Data) * msg.nr);
```

Similarly, on the receiver end, call `memcpy` two times to for the `Message` and the array of `Data`.

```c
Message rcv;
memcpy(&rcv, buffer, sizeof(Message));
rcv.data = malloc(sizeof(Data) * rcv.nr);
memcpy(rcv.data, buffer + sizeof(Message), sizeof(Data) * rcv.nr);
```

[Try it interactively on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s6haePrK1)

**Solution for size-limited array**

If it's acceptable to have the `data` array to have a fixed maximum size `NUM_DATA_MAX`, then (de)serialization can be done with 1, instead of 2, calls to `memcpy`. To do so, define `Message` to contain an array `data`, instead of a pointer to an array.

```c
#define NUM_DATA_MAX 10

typedef struct Data {
    int valid;
    double value;
} Data;

typedef struct Message {
    int id;
    int size;
    int nr;
    Data data[NUM_DATA_MAX];
} Message;
```

On the sender end

```c
int bufferSize = sizeof(Message);
BYTE* buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
memcpy(buffer, &msg, sizeof(Message));
```

On the receiver end

```c
Message rcv;
memcpy(&rcv, buffer, sizeof(Message));
```

Comment: Previously I didn't notice that the `data` field of `Message` is an array. I've updated the answer to handle the array correctly.

Comment: Updated again to include an alternative solution.